# Objective-C inheritance duplicate code issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `FilesViewController`, `ShareViewController` and `UICusomtTableViewCell` objects that contain `UICollectionView` and its delegate method:

```
- numberOfSectionsInCollectionView

- numberOfItemsInSection

- cellForItemAtIndexPath
```

So the last method looks like this:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SNFileCollectionViewCell *cell = (SNFileCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"FileCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    SNTestFile *file = [self.files objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    [cell setText:file.name];
    [cell setImage:file.image];

    return cell;
}
```

For all these objects I listed above the cellForItemAtIndexPath method does the same thing - it creates cells, so to optimise my code I have created `BaseViewController : UIViewController` and put this method there and right now `FilesViewController` and `ShareViewController` inherit from `BaseViewController` and have the same functionality for creation cells, and I don't need duplicate code.

But as `UICusomtTableViewCell` this is an another of `UIViewController` subclass, I can't inherit from BaseViewController, because this is another stuff.

So it means I can't inherit the part of functionality that I need and it means I need to duplicate code, that is not a good practice, because if some thing in the project does the same, good programmer never will duplicate it.

What you can suggest?

So the idea is just to have one part of the same code in one place, then I can modify only one point instead of lot of points. You know what I mean.

Comment: With all that OOP idioms it is easy to forget that code duplication issues can always be solved with regular helper functions shared across a bunch of modules.

Answer (score 0):

As a variant you can create separate class, lets name it blablablaHelper, that has only static methods. Add methods + (Cell *) createBlablabla:()...And use it in all 3 classes instead of doing the base class.

Comment: you're meaning like extend category of NSObject?

Comment: He meant creating helper class that will contain static class methods, unrelated to any specific class or instance. Then call common method from each of three -[collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:]'s. @MatrosovAlexander

Comment: extend NSObject is not so good in this situation because you will use it only in a limited count of places. I mean you can create another class in your Utils folder like ShareCodeHelper or more specific, I have about 6 different helpers (AutolayoutHelper, ModuleHelper, ServiceHelper, ProviderHelper etc) where I have a common methods as static (+) and use them everywhere.In your case you can add e.g. +()createCellAtIndexPath()InCollectionView() method. and use this method as [blablablaHelper createCellAtIndexPath...] in all 3 places.In this case you will have one code to change then.

Comment: do you need then point my uicollectionview to set as delegate blablablaHelper object?

Comment: createCellAtIndexPath is delegate method so it is not a static one

Comment: no delegates. you move the body of the method to the common place. and then use it like:  - (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   return [..Helper createCellAtIndexPath() inCollectionView() withIdentifier:()];
}